# TypeScript overriding extended class method that uses decorator gives old method

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-decorator, typescript-class

That gives the old value of the method before being overridden. How I can get the final value there?

```
const a = {} as any

class Parent {
    @D()
    public doSomething(b: any) {
        console.log('parent')
    }
}

class Child extends Parent{
    public override doSomething() {
        console.log('child')
    }
}

const child = new Child()
child.doSomething()

function D () {
    return function(target: any, property: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        console.log('assign')
        a[property] = target[property]
    }
}

setTimeout(a.doSomething, 1000)   // here it gives "parent" but it should be "child"
```

[Here is the demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?experimentalDecorators=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA3gX3heYCeAoA4AGzgiwAU4AnAUzFhTxmZgAEARACgEomWAHAK4AjIgEtgMACYgAyiAC2NKAAsxYAOadhALmw5uqPixahIIIjQB0REFoDk-anSj3eJtHk95ipLAGE1IikYGgAPKDopCmd6RhMhUQkYEAA3GioqMSkaaTlFZTVNHiMTEzMIC2tbB2AgqTdjGE9vCtg6sWCkGDAaAHcYQM6pHh96qxl5JVV1LV48ADNBMGAoMXAYdhgS%20JZaKEEqMBgllbXwTihqDWU9OFwAGhh%20KhB%20DKgcPWgszSeciDALL8KAgKh6civd5UT7sGiA4GgqiGXZlGAVKo2Oycex%20MQaMCNNHMOAAbRebw%20OAAut0rlQblByVCqdSmi0CBBlAAVMRKECCKCcOATfLTIoaJ4ARgADHLuEA)

How I can assign the actual value there, the one that calls "child"?

Comment: I'm not inclined to spend effort on old-style decorators so this isn't going to directly answer your question. Still, the gist is the same: the only way this would work is if your overriding method is itself decorated, or if it calls `super`'s decorated method. And you'll need to change your decorator so code that actually gets called every time the method is called instead of once per decorated method. Using new decorators, [this playground link](//tsplay.dev/wExG4W) shows the possibilities. I'd write this up as an answer if you like, if you're okay switching to newer decorators. Let me know.

Comment: I am using ts version 4.9.4, is it possible to do something with the current version of the decorators?

Comment: I don't understand the sense of "current".  If you mean new ES decorators, they are only supported in TS5.0 and above, so you'll need to upgrade if you want to use them.   If you mean old TS decorators, something could probably be done but I'm not inclined to spend effort on it.  Please clarify.

Comment: I decided to update to the latest version. I can use the new decorators. You can put it as answer. But I am not sure how to toggle between old and new decorators.

Comment: Don't use the `--experimentalDecorators` compiler option and it will start using the new ones.  I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Comment: I did this but they still come with old style values, like the second argument in method decorator should be an object, but it comes as before, the property name as string

Comment: I'm not sure what to say; configuring your compiler is probably something only you can do, or at any rate it's out of scope for this question so I don't want to focus on it here in comments.  Does your acceptance or rejection of a possible answer depend on this or can we treat that as a separate issue?

Comment: I will accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what follows I will be using [JavaScript decorators](https://2ality.com/2022/10/javascript-decorators.html) which are supported [starting with in TypeScript 5.0](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#decorators).  I won't spend time looking at [legacy/experimental TypeScript decorators](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) as represented by the code in the question.  Legacy decorators aren't actually deprecated, but they are not going to be developed anymore and eventually they will be harder to use than to avoid.

---

There are two general issues with the code in the question that prevent it from working as intended.

First: the decorator function itself is called once per method *declaration*, not per method *call*. So the original code only sets `a.doSomething`once. If you want something to happen every time a decorated method is *called*, you will need your decorator to *wrap* the method.  So the decorator function is called once, and it uses that opportunity to modify the method it's decorating:

```
const a = {} as any   
function D(originalMethod: any, context: ClassMethodDecoratorContext) {
    const methodName = String(context.name);
    function replacementMethod(this: any, ...args: any[]) {
        a[methodName] = this[methodName].bind(this);
        const result = originalMethod.call(this, ...args);
        return result;
    }
    return replacementMethod;
}

class Parent {
    @D
    public doSomething() {
        console.log('parent')
    }
}
```

Next, there's no reasonable way to modify the behavior of subclass methods that *override* a decorated superclass method.  Overriding methods don't interact with their superclass method merely by existing.  So if you want a subclass method call to trigger the decorated behavior, you'll either need to decorate the subclass method itself:

```
class Child extends Parent {
    @D // <-- explicitly decorate subclass method
    public override doSomething() {
        console.log('childDecorateSub');
    }
}

const child = new Child();
child.doSomething(); // "childDecorateSub" 
a.doSomething(); // "childDecorateSub"
```

Or you'll have to call the decorated method on `super`

```
class Child extends Parent {
    public override doSomething() {
        console.log('childSuperCall');
        super.doSomething(); // <-- explicitly call 
        // decorated superclass method
    }
}

const child = new Child()
child.doSomething(); // "childSuperCall", "parent" 
a.doSomething(); // "childSuperCall", "parent"
```

It depends on the behavior you want to see.  But one of those should hopefully work for you.

---

Notice I said "no reasonable way" for subclass methods to inherit the decorator from superclass methods.  It might be technically possible to do some crazy proxying of the superclass's prototype so that when you make a subclass it automatically re-decorates methods, but I wouldn't want to begin implementing something like that, since it's likely to be incredibly fragile.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#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-kugmruubbQYw4mSdJslIvJs54N8QA)